# Set added row as first indexPath row

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have 3 segmented controller views, and one I have added an additional custom cell to the tableview. My question is how do I set a custom cell in one of the cases to always be set at the top of a tableView when the view loads? Thanks!

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

    {



    case 0:
        myCell.textLabel!.text = globalList[indexPath.row]
        break

    case 1:
        myCell.textLabel!.text = friendsList[indexPath.row]
        break


    case 2:

    // *** I want to add a Cell here with a "Add Item" IBAction ---------------------

        if(indexPath.row == meList.count) {

            myCell.textLabel?.text = "+ Add Item"
            // add new row here
            /* OR add new button here as cell's subview  */
            // set frame of your button
            // set target and selector method of button
            // [cell addSubView: addButton]

        }
        else {

            myCell.textLabel?.text = meList[indexPath.row]
        }


    default:
        break


    }

    return myCell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, you need to `+ 1` the number you return so there's an extra row. (Only do this if `mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2`.)

Then in `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`, if `mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2` and `indexPath.row == 0` (the first cell), configure and return your "add items" cell.

This insertion of an extra row will offset all your indices by 1. So in the `else` statement, you'll want `myCell.textLabel?.text = meList[indexPath.row - 1]`. This way, for example, you'll return the first element of the array (the 0th index) when `indexPath.row == 1`.